# Edges appear with (unwanted) subdivisions (many vertex). How to change/remove?

Tags: modeling

(blender 2.81) beginner.

I need some help, please.

(edit mode). Do you know how I see these vertex? they are making a subdivision of the main edge. I think I did nothing to create them.

How can I go back to regular view? (without them)

thank you.[image]

[image]

Comment: Select edges > press delete > limited dissolve

Comment: thank you @SergeL,
it worked fine.

Comment: The problem is still there, I can solve the proble using "Limited Dissolve" but I don't undertand why this subdivision appears, and how to avoid them. The problem appears when deleting a face.

Comment: Share a file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com or part of it which represents the issue.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=o6OwV13b" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/o6OwV13b/)

Comment: hi @SergeL, 

Do you know what is wrong with the file? there is an open square where you can see the tiny edge subdivisions created when I removed the faces.

Also, how can I mark your reply as the answer? I don’t see any place to do that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see subdivided lines, but couldn't reproduce the issue. When I delete a face everything behaves as usual. Maybe you can add exact steps to reproduce it. Or try newer version of Blender from https://builder.blender.org/download/

Comment: I found the issue (i think), please see the attached pictures. If you zoom in in that open square you will see a tiny thickness. BTW, how can I attach here new screenshots?

Comment: Use "edit" button under the tags to add pics. Regarding thickness - yes I saw it in your file. It's a result of solidify modifier, which was enabled to preview in edit mode - see modifier stack settings for it.